# UISearchBar and pass data to another view controller

Tags: swift, xcode

There is table view to show phone contact and a search Bar in view controller . I implemented the code for the search-bar to filter givenName array it works just fine but when I click on the cell that I searched it doesn’t display the right information it displays only the information of the first row( exactly first index). The question it is how i can solve this problem ?

**Data Model :**

```
struct ContactStruct {
    let identifier : String
    let thumbnailImageData : UIImage
    let givenName : String
    let familyName : String
    let phoneNumbers : String
    let emailAddresses : String
}
```

**Main View controller :**

```
        class NewContactViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

         var contactsData = [ContactStruct]()
         var searchedContact = [String]()
         var searching = false

       @IBOutlet weak var tblMain: UITableView!
       @IBOutlet weak var contactSearchBar: UISearchBar!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
    }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InsertContactViewController") as! InsertContactViewController
          vc.strEditFitstName = contactsData[indexPath.row].givenName
          vc.stridentifier = contactsData[indexPath.row].identifier
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
       } 

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if searching {
         return searchedContact.count
      } else {
         return contactsData.count
      }
   }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell") as! NewContactCell
      let contactToDisplay = contactsData[indexPath.row]
   contactToDisplay.familyName
      cell.lblLName.text = contactToDisplay.givenName

      return cell
   }
```

**search bar methods:**

```
extension NewContactViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
      let givenNames = contactsData.map { $0.givenName }
      searchedContact = givenNames.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
      searching = true
      tblMain.reloadData()
   }
   func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      searching = false
      searchBar.text = ""
      tblMain.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Comment: Show below the answer and replace my string Array with your ContactStruct Array.

Answer (score 1):

Follow just below code as an example :

```
            let countriesList = ["African Union",
                                 "Andorra",
                                 "Armenia",
                                 "Austria",
                                 "Bahamas",
                                 "Barbados",
                                 "Belarus",
                                 "Belgium",
                                 ]
            @IBOutlet var tblPlace: UITableView!
            @IBOutlet var searchPlace: UISearchBar!
            var selctedCountries:[String] = []
            var filteredData: [String]!

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()
                    searchPlace.delegate = self
                    filteredData = countriesList
                }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return filteredData.count
        }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ApplyFilterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ApplyFilterTableViewCell

            cell.lblName = filteredData[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InsertContactViewController") as! InsertContactViewController
        vc.strEditFitstName = filteredData[indexPath.row]

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

     func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

            filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? countriesList : countriesList.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
                // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
                return dataString.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            })

            tblPlace.reloadData()
        }
```